# Coloring substring of a string

Tags: android-studio

I have a string with numbers and i want to color the part after the dot.

i use this code.

```
String number="123456.2585";
number = number.replace("5", "<font color='#EE0000'>5</font>");
editText2.setText(Html.fromHtml(number));
```

There is no problem and the final string come with only the digit 5 colored in red.

Now when i want to color only a substring, the part after the dot. It does not work. why?

this is the code that does not work

```
 String number="123456.2585";
 String str=number.substring(7,number.length()); 
 number = number.replace(str, "<font color='#EE0000'>str</font>");
 editText2.setText(Html.fromHtml(number));
```

I mean it work but i only get the string after the dot, i want to have all the string with the substring colored!

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is you are passing the substring = "str"
Just add the proper double quotes "" and the plus symbol for string concatenation you will get the accurate result.

Add this below instead of **str**

```
"+  str +"
```

your final look will be

```
number = number.replace(str, "<font color='#EE0000'>" + str + "</font>");
```